# XCode Simulator: how to change its shortcuts?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7

When the simulator in XCode is running, the default shortcuts for rotation are Cmd+Left and Cmd+Right.

Is there any way to change them? For example, change them to Ctrl+Left & Ctrl+Right?

Comment: @dasdom see the accepted answer. Yes, you can. I couldn't find the solution anywhere but Jason did provide a way to change it. It's a wonderful solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was able to change Simulator shortcuts by doing the following:

1. Open Simulator
2. Right click the icon in the tray
3. Select Options > Show in Finder
4. Copy Simulator.app to your /Applications directory

At this point, you won't be able to run Simulator.app from the /Applications directory, but that's ok, we're just going to use it there for setting the shortcut(s). To do that, follow the steps you would to change any other app's shortcuts:

1. System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts
2. App Shortcuts > add [+]
3. Select the Simulator.app from the list (wouldn't appear unless we had already completed the steps above.)
4. Exact name of Menu item and shortcut.
5. Add

Now go ahead and delete Simulator.app from /Applications. The shortcut will still be changeable and the app will be listed from now on.

Comment: Awesome! I tried your method and it works great! Now I can set them to Ctrl-Left/Right because I have been using Cmd-Left/Right for the other purpose for a long time.

Comment: Thank you, very useful to have a better shortcut into the Shake Gesture when using expo :-)

Answer (score 8):

I could use [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34363515/2870968) without having to duplicate Simulator.app into Applications and then delete it.

Not sure the needed Other... and Search options required some particular MacOS, so I'm copying the adapted steps here :

1. System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts
2. App Shortcuts > add [+]
3. Open list of Applications, select Other... at the bottom
4. Use the search box to search for Simulator.app
5. Simulator.app should appear, double click it
6. Exact name of Menu item, and shortcut
7. Add