# Can't open dev menu via CMD+D or reload via CMD+R any longer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I can't open my dev menu via CMD+D or reload via CMD+R any longer. It just stopped working without me knowingly changing something.

Some more info:

- Shake gesture still works, but not always
- Live reload works only when shake gesture is working
- Independent of build via `react-native run-ios` or via xCode
- rn22.0 and rn23.0-rc
- same behaviour upon `react-native init newProject`
- I use the workspace file

What I have tried to fix it:

- tried other simulators
- downgrade/upgrades by a version
- ran `react-native upgrade` and said `yes` to every overwrite
- complete reinstall of all NPM modules
- Reset the simulator
- clean build
- reboot

Comment: May be in xCode you are in 'Release' configuration?

Comment: @Cherniv, you mean under Products => Scheme => Edit Scheme => Run? Thats still under Debug

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Have you tried accessing the Simulators Hardware?

Simulator > Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard

Comment: thanks, so there is the shortcut I must have accidentally pressed. Still wonder why it did not reset upon "Reset Contents & Settings".

Comment: Does not work for me either.
Also menu changed with latest XCode, it's now under I/O > Keyboard  > Connect Hardware Keyboard.

Comment: See my comment below https://stackoverflow.com/a/62012335/1662864

Comment: In my case, (Version 11.3.1):

Hardware -> Keyboard -> Send Keyboard Shortcuts to Device

Answer (score 55):

From Menu Bar, I/O  -> Input -> Send Keyboard Input to Device. It really helps.

Answer (score 45):

`I/O -> Input -> Send Keyboard Input to Device` is not working properly always for me.

I use `Device -> Shake` to open the dev menu using the following shortcut:

```
CMD+CTR+Z
```

Comment: I can confirm. CMD+D is a hit or miss for me. On the other hand, using the proposed `Device -> Shake` works every time

Answer (score 21):

This is indeed really annoying. I figured out a solution I haven't seen here yet, and hope it helps anyone. Go to `I/O -> Input -> Send Keyboard Input to Device`. And you'll see next time you press `CMD+D` or `CMD+R` it'll work. However, it somehow resets this every time. To overcome this, simply add a *system keyboard shortcut*:

`Send Keyboard Input to Device` => `CMD+D`

Now every time you press the shortcut, it'll also invoke that command to make sure the shortcut is sent to the app.

See [here for how to add system keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62728594/2870968) if need be.

Comment: This works the best because it will fix it even when it resets itself. Thanks for the idea

Comment: it is the best.

Comment: Simulator is not in my list of applications

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue with IOS Simulator. First check your build type ie it is debug or release. For this
i) Open your project in XCode and go to
`Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme` and check the Build Configuration if it is Release then change it to the Debug because `cmd+d` or `cmd+r` commands are run only for debug mode release.
ii) If Build Configuration is already set to Debug then **Restart** your **simulator** by going to `Hardware -> Restart` This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 8):

In terminal, you can press "D" like below.

```
Loading dependency graph, done.

To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

info Opening developer menu...
```

Comment: I am not getting this option I am using react-native 0.62, earlier I was getting, but now I didn't

Answer (score 7):

**Ctrl + CMD + Z (iOS)**

**Cmd + M (Android)**

Using v0.70 of react native.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32848237)

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>
pops up the React Native Debug Menu

Answer (score 4):

One thing that works for me on Mac is to press the key combination with Option first.

- So to restart:   Opt + R followed by Cmd + R
- Debug remote JS: Opt + D followed by Cmd + D

Absolutely no idea why it works, but it works for me (MacBook Pro with touchbar, Expo 37 / React Native 61)

Answer (score 4):

For me, I went to the Device in the simulator top menu and clicked `shake` then it got opened.[image]

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>⌃ Control</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> shakes IOS simulator and opens React Native Debug Menu

also try this on Simulator menu

```
I/O > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard
```

Answer (score 3):

If the shortcuts don't work, do this :

- On the top left of your mac when simulator is selected you must see `Device` in the menu.
- Click on it, there you'll see `Shake` option.
- Just click that and the dev menu should show up!

This works for me! I'm on XCode 14.0 if this helps in someway.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a custom configuration other than `Debug` and you're using Cocoapods, make sure the `Podfile` specifies that that configuration should be a `debug` configuration. By default it is assumed to be a `release` configuration. Add the following line to the top of your `Podfile` (assuming your custom configuration is named "Staging"):

For pre-1.0 Cocoapods use [`xcodeproj`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#xcodeproj):

```
xcodeproj 'MyProject', 'Staging' => :debug
```

For Cocoapods 1.0+ use [`project`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#project):

```
project 'MyProject', 'Staging' => :debug
```

Then, to get the `Pods.xcodeproj` file to update:

```
rm -rf Pods/
pod install
```

This will ensure the `DEBUG=1` Preprocessor Macro is set for the `Staging` configuration for the `Pods` project.

Comment: do you happen to remember where in the `Podfile` that additional line belongs? For example, before the `target 'AppName' do` line, right next to `platform :ios, '9.0'`

Comment: @PatNeedham That should do it. Check out the [Cocoapods `project` documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#project) for more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with expo + VSCode on windows.

Shaking the device didn't open the developers menu anymore.

I was able to solve the issue after an hour of frustration by openning "settings.json" file under ".expo" folder in VSCode and add the line   "dev": true.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue (however on an Android emulator on a Windows machine, but I'll just post it here if anyone else has that issue). Basically it happened after enabling/disabling num lock. Try to toggle your num lock and see if that helps?

Comment: thanks, but there is no such key on a mac. Also, CMD+R works just fine in Chrome e.g.

Answer (score 0):

for people who have two or more languages in your keyboard, make sure that you're setting the language to **English** before you hit `CMD + D` or  `CMD + R`.

for me, I have `Arabic` and `English` languages and I was hitting `CMD + ي` not `CMD + D`

Answer (score 0):

「Connect Hardware Keyboard」's always not working, either

try I/O -> Input -> Send Keyboard Input to Device

Answer (score -1):

I think **Simulator** -> **Device** -> **Restart** fixes my issue