# Is there a quick way to toggle dark mode in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-darkmode

I'm mainly using the Android emulator for development. Is there a quick way (ideally a keyboard shortcut) to switch between dark mode and light mode for testing the dark/light themes?

Comment: I am hoping for a solution similar to the one for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59886562/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-dark-mode-and-light-mode-in-iphon

Comment: Not on the emulator but on the layout editor you can just press  `N`

Comment: You should be able to add the dark mode tile in the notification shade, as you do with an actual device.

Answer (score 11):

If you use MacOS, you can automate this action with a shortcut:

1. Open Shortcuts.app
2. Find action "Run shell script"
3. Insert this script:

```bash
alias adb="/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb"
if [[ $(adb shell "cmd uimode night") == "Night mode: yes" ]]; then
  adb shell "cmd uimode night no"
else
  adb shell "cmd uimode night yes"
fi
```

4. Select "Shortcut details" tab on the top right ("i" icon), click Add keyboard shortcut and add your shortcut.

Here is an example:

[image: shortcuts example]

Works perfectly!

[image: shortcut gif]

Answer (score 9):

Just to bring more visibility to the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673335/is-there-a-quick-way-to-toggle-dark-mode-in-the-android-emulator#comment121364132_68673335) with a great solution:

> You should be able to add the dark mode tile in the [swipe down] notification shade, as you do with an actual device.

Obviously it will change slightly depending on the phone you are emulating but here is a demo for anyone not used to Android devices

[image: dark mode in notification shade demo]