# How to change Record Screen shortcut key (Command + R) in Xcode simulator?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode12.5

in the Xcode 12.5, apple has released a new feature that we can record simulator screen with easy shortcut key `Command+R`.

but in the switch between Simulator and Xcode to run and build project, because when we want build project and run in simulator we also press `Command+R`, we have problem with this shortcut key in Simulator and see recording has started but we don't want to.

so how can we change this shortcut in Simulator to avoid this conflict?

[image]

Comment: Then dont use Command+R to run project or just change run key shortcut

Comment: Look into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259578/xcode-simulator-how-to-change-its-shortcuts

Comment: It is quite easy to change a keyboard shortcut of a Mac app. But how to do that is not a programming matter. This should be migrated to AskDifferent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open Simulator
2. Right click the icon in the tray
3. Select Options > Show in Finder
4. Copy Simulator.app to your /Applications directory
5. Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts
6. Click App Shortcuts > add [+]
7. Select the Simulator.app from the list
8. Enter Menu Title `Record Screen` (or other name of the Simulator's Shortcut)
9. Enter Keyboard Shortcut whatever you want
10. Click Add
11. Delete Simulator.app from /Applications
12. Done! The shortcut will still be changeable.

[image]

Comment: Helpful! Got confused by why the **first 4 steps** were necessary, but later realized doing this **adds this option to the dropdown** in `Keyboard Shortcuts` -> `App Shortcuts`.

Answer (score 3):

Without copying Simulator:

1. ⌘ + click the Simulator icon in the dock
2. Open System Settings and search for "Keyboard shortcuts"
3. Select "Keyboard shortcuts" under "Keyboard"
4. Select "App Shortcuts"
5. Click the + button
6. Click on the application dropdown and select "Other..."
7. Drag the Simulator app from Finder to the open dialog
8. Click "Open"
9. Set "Menu Title" to "Record Screen"
10. Set your desired keyboard shortcut
11. Click "Done"
12. Click "Done"

[image: Demo]